# Why do my members see each others data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication, formsauthenticationticket

I am working on an asp.net application, all is going well so far except multiple users. I have created a login system based in SQL Server. The process is as follows... User provides username and password. These are verified via sql server. if verified they are stored in a forms authorization ticket. This ticket is used to then provide additional data on the users application page once logged in. The problem is that it would seem there can only be one of these at a time in the application? If one user (call him "Joe") logs in and starts working, then another user (call him "Frank") on another computer logs in and starts working, the next databind on "Joe's" computer binds "Frank's" data. Where am I going wrong? Any good reading or suggestions on the matter?

Comment: Are you storing data in a `static` field or `Cache`, ? they will be shared among all users.

Comment: It's a static field. Is that where I'm screwing up here?

Comment: Yes, if it is static, then it will be shared among your users.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the class where you are storing the application data is not static.  Subsequently none of the fields should be static either.